# Can't get Font-Awesome Icons to display

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

So for some reason font-awesome icons won't display while Lineicons do.

If you open the menu (you'll have to make your window lss than 700px width)
You can see that the menu icon opens the menu. Below I placed the following code

```
<li><a href="#" class="icon icon-user">Data Management</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa-user">Location</a></li>
```

As you can see the first icon by LineIcons is being display while the "fa-user" icon from Font-Awesome won't display. I'm unsure why I also had to add the word icon before "icon-user" but it was the only way to get it to work.

Here's the page I'm testing it on : [Here](http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/)

Comment: Add a class of `fa` too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add "fa" in front of fa-user

```
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-user">Location</a></li>
```

This will solve your display problem.

Comment: is just appears as a square though @ArneRie

Answer (score 3):

I always recommend to use the CDN loaded version.

Here:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Icons:</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> fa fa-user</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> fa fa-remove</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I have already loaded the font in the header from the site itself. I also tried the <i class> thing but still shows up as blank squares.

Comment: @コードバリノ , have you cleared your browser cache (just to eliminate the possibility) ? Altough, i REALLY recommend using the CDN loaded version.

Comment: Yes, also have you visited the page? Does it load on your browser?

Comment: @コードバリノ, yep just did. And no, it doesnt load :/ when using WP, try adding my head tags inside the post

Comment: Wait its some issue on my part, for some reason it loads it with your script but not from mine?

Comment: @コードバリノ, could be an error in the plugin maybe, in your themes header.php file add the CDN version, and you should be fine :)

Comment: I'm enqueue it though, it even shows up already in the header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88658/discussion-between-kristian-hareland-and--).

Answer (score 0):

On their site the cdn is without the https. Try adding it!

Answer (score 0):

Sir dont use bootstrapcdn use this  hope this work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: why do not use the CDN?

Comment: i try use that    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 its not working